# clang-format style option for space after return type

Tags: objective-c, clang-format

I would like to find out which of the clang-format style options is responsible for inserting (or removing) the space between return type and method name in Objective-C. I am unable to find this option in the clang-format style guide.

example:

```
- (id) init;
```

vs.

```
- (id)init;
```

Comment: Did you ever find the option to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Let me know if you find something out :)

Comment: I've just come across this. Still no solution?

Answer (score 1):

As of 3.7.0, clang-format doesn't support this option.

I have therefore created a patch that adds in an option for this functionality. The patch, and a binary (for Mac), can be found here: https://github.com/ebaker355/clang-format